# How do I compile a crosscompiler targeting Linux x64 on a Windows host?

Tags: windows, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, distcc

I am planning on harvesting my gaming HTPCs spare cycles for compiling my software using distcc, but I will need to set up a cross compiler. The problem is that Google is sadly lacking in relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Cygwin is the purest form of evil, but is the easiest way of doing what you want.
You will just have to install the correct version of gcc from the cygwin installer.

This website has the answer [here](http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html)